# How do you completly remove an item from modded minecraft (no creative inventory or JEI and not just remove recipe)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

What is the easiest way to remove an item in modded Minecraft? I want to make it impossible to obtain, and erase any references to it, such as jei. Preferably, this could be done with the help of other mods, rather than coding it myself.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're asking. What do you mean by "remove an item from modded Minecraft?" Can you [edit] your post to clarify?

Comment: @expertCoder14
I'm askinng how to completly remove an item so people cannot view it in JEI, creative inventory, or anywhere else it can show up.

Comment: What type of methods are you open to to accomplish your task? If you're planning to write code in Java, this might be better suited for GameDev.SE.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I'm not writing any java I'm just deleting items

Comment: Then what methods are you open to in order to delete the items from the mod?

Comment: Any way I can do other than just removing the recipe

Many mekanism tools are clogging JEI